# 2 FIFOs 1 Task - Synchronize them

Tags: c, fifo

I have the following problem:

I have to launch a process from various terminals but I only can start running the program after a certain number of processes has started. In other words, I have to block somehow the processes until I get the right number of processes.

I'm trying to do that using FIFOs by using the first process called as a "server". The problem is resumed as a ticket entrance problem: The "server" process is always writing in a FIFO which will be the number of the next process. The next process take its "ticket" and send to the "server" his number++. I coded like this, basically:

SERVER:

```
count = 0;
fd_w = open ("client", O_WRONLY);
fd_r = open ("server", O_RDONLY);
do {
    write (fd_w, &count, sizeof(int)); //Write on client's reading FIFO
    read (fd_r, &count, sizeof(int));  //Read what clients wrote
    printf ("Msg read: %d\n", count);
} while (count != 4);

printf ("Starting...\n");
```

CLIENT:

```
fd_r = open ("client", O_RDONLY);
fd_w = open ("server", O_WRONLY);

read (fd_r, &count, sizeof(int)); // Read the ticket from server

count++;

write (fd_w, &count, sizeof(int)); // Write what should be the next ticket

//Wait until we have 4 processes
```

What happens is that the server waits the first call but when the first process arrives it reads right the server message, put right the message back to the server but the server somehow interact 1 or 2 in loop (it seems to be kinda random) and simply ends. Without even print "Starting...". Any ideas why is this happening? Also, any ideas how should I notify the other process that they can go on?

If it matters, I'm actually using the same code for Server and Client, I check which is which by making a test if the "Server" FIFO was already created. But I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: what do you think is a FIFO?  All I see is you opening a couple files.

Comment: Always check (and handle) the result of system calls (`read()` and `write()` in this case).

Comment: xaxxon, I'm using the FIFO as interprocess comunications. I'm creating them earlier in the code using mkfifo and unlinking them in the end as well. Isn't it? Alk, I will.

Comment: It is not clear how the clients are going to know that there are 4 processes.  The first client will read 0 and write 1 — where does it get 4 from?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in you program. First note that FIFO semantics are different from that of regular files.

If you open a FIFO in read only (`O_RDONLY`) or write only (`O_WRONLY`) modes, those open calls would block until the FIFO is also opened in write only/read write (`O_WRONLY/O_RDWR`)or read only (O_RDONLY) modes respectively. If you want your open calls to return immediately irrespective of the above condition then you will have to open the FIFO in non-blocking and read only (`O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK`) mode or in read write mode (`O_RDWR`).

If you open with (`O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK`) flags then you will receive an `EAGAIN` error immediately for every `read()` unless the FIFO is also not opened for writing. But if you open it for both read and write (`O_RDWR`) then your read will block until data is available in the FIFO. It makes sense because it ensures that there is at least one writer and one reader on this FIFO.

Also you haven't done error checking in your code, that obfuscates coding errors and makes debugging harder.

I have fixed the `SERVER` code, so that it works as expected.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int count = 0;
    int fd_w = open ("client-fifo", O_RDWR);
    if (fd_w < 0) {
            perror("open");
            exit(-1);
        }
    int fd_r = open ("server-fifo", O_RDWR);
    if (fd_r < 0) {
            perror("open");
            exit(-1);
        }   
    do {
        if (write (fd_w, &count, sizeof(int)) < 0) { //Write
                perror("write");
                exit(-1);
        }
        if (read (fd_r, &count, sizeof(int)) < 0) {  //Read
                perror("read");
                exit(-1);
        }

    } while (count != 4);

    printf ("Starting...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need `exit(-1);` after the `perror("open");` calls (and additional braces), or create a function that calls `perror()` and `exit()` and use that.